# Do both of these introductions mean the same thing and make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, politeness, business-language

I work with someone whom I have not yet introduced myself to; someone usually introduces a new person around the office but I wasn’t in on this person’s first day, so I missed that.

Anyway, on introducing myself, I was wondering if the following would make sense?

> I don’t know that we have been introduced.

Does it mean the same thing as:

> I don’t think we’ve been introduced.

Comment: Yes, thet both make sense and have the same meaning (more or less), though the second  feels a little more natural and less stuffy.

Comment: Please have extended discussions in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both phrases point to the same sentiment of being *fairly certain* that the speaker has *not* been introduced. The register is different however, the first implying a snobbishness absent from the second (note that it is not necessarily more formal, only more pretentious, e.g. something one might expect to hear from a James Bond villain).

Comment: Haha, cheers digitalfishpond!